# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't see my SSD drive

Tags: bios, disc

Just recently I'd bought a two disc Asus G750 laptop with intention to use Ubuntu and Windows 8.1.
I decided to install Windows first. I've assigned 350 out of 450GBs to Windows leaving the rest of the SSD unformatted. The other disc (HDD) also remained untouched.
Windows' installation was successful, so I've run Ubuntu 14.04 installation.
Unfortunatelly the installator doesn't see my SSD drive, only the HDD one.

I've looked into /dev/ to see that only HDD is visible, tried to mount disc "blindly" (since HDD was sda I tried to mount sdb..), no luck.

After that I've put my Windows DVD, running its' installator to check if it sees both discs. It does.

**edit**:

while on Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD

```
sudo parted -l
```

gives me the following:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number Start   End    Size   Type     File system   Flags
1      1049kB  17.0G  17.0G  primary  linux-swap(1) boot
2      17.0G   1000GB 983GB  extended 
5      17.0G   1000GB 983GB  logical  ext4

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read write (Read-only file system). /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
```

## dmesg | less -p"error|fail|warn"

Since log is quite big, I put it on GitHub's Gist. [Full log here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c34811a91ef2f0a4735c)

Could anybody give me a hand with this?

Comment: You have traces of this trouble: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=170074 - `(20131115/nsarguments-95)` -lines in your dmesg output. Might be related to `nouveau ... init failed, -16`. If you have a dual gfx-card setup (i.e. Intel + Nvida) you might need to investigate that - e.g. you might need `Bumblebee`. Moreover, the messages ending with `(20131115/utaddress-251)` indicates some kind of ACPI trouble. Maybe try to update BIOS if you can find a newer one.

Comment: `Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!` might give a clue on why you do not see the second disk. Run either `sudo gnome-disks &` or `sudo gparted &` from the Terminal and you should be able to find the disk and its name at least. You might need to repartition it entirely, even sweeping the partition table off the disk.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this:

Read "To temporarily add a boot parameter to a kernel" at https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/289138

NOTE:
this might well require doing it for every (re)boot during the installation process
and later require to have it added permanently using the description below the temporary method (link above).

Replace `foo=bar` in the description with `libata.noacpi=1` .
And remember to use at least one space char to separate it from other options.

From what I understand there are ACPI data *missing* in certain ASUS Motherboard BIOS'es
that make the Linux ACPI driver fail to load at times.

## Getting further:

To get more info on WHAT the problem is; open a Terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or the icon in the launcher.
Then type: `dmesg | less -p"error|fail|warn"` at the `$` prompt, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Use <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> (next, previous) to jump from each match on the search (which is defined after `-p` above). Also note that <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> moves the text up/down so that you may see what is above and below the found matches.
<kbd>q</kbd> quits `less`, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> closes the terminal.

Add text to your question above to fill in what you find.
*A line of text followed by `==` on the next line creates a heading.*

Comment: Unfortunately adding `libata.noacpi=1` as boot option doesn't solve my problem. Still only HDD drive is visible :(

Comment: Updated above...

Comment: I've realized just realized that while installing Windows 8.1 I deleted EFI boot partition and Asus resque  partition. Before I move any further I want to restore a valid disks state.